# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl'

Tags: php, xampp

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\intl (No se puede encontrar el m≤dulo especificado.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_intl.dll (No se puede encontrar el m≤dulo especificado.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Xampp client won't work when intl php extension is enabled.

Setup:

- Windows 10
- Xampp with php 7.3.2

Steps to reproduce:

- Uncheck extension=intl
- Add C:\xampp\php on system path
- Checked php_intl.dll exisits in C:\xampp\php\ext\
- Add to system var C:\xampp\php
- Make sure extension_dir is correct, now set to extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"
- Restarting after applying changes

Comment: There are actual some Bugs with xampp 7.3.2 x64
They are working on it (https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=77933)

Comment: Thanks!!!! Link you provided has a post explaining the 64bit lacks a .dll, And actually hours ago a new version was released addressing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BUG (community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=77933)